# image enlargement on mouseover

Tags: java, image

Is there any simple way in java to enlarge an image when a mouse rollls over it?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs525e/s01/java/Y.html).

Comment: Swing? AWT? SWT? Other?  Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)